# Can roots of an algebraic equation be neither real nor complex?

Tags: complex-numbers

My usually understanding tells me that an algebraic equation can intersect the x-axis, touch it, or not touch it. In which cases I will get a real root, coinciding real root, and an imaginary root (conjugate pair) respectively.
*Note that I am considering real coefficients only.*
But consider the following:

> The quadratic equation $p(x) = 0$ with real coefficients has purely imaginary roots. Then the equation $p(p(x)) = 0$ has what type of roots?

Since $p(x)$ can become zero only on input of some complex numbers, I get the sense that the roots of the equation $p(p(x)) = 0$ will also be imaginary. But this is all based on intuition.

The answer provided to me was that *The roots are neither real nor purely imaginary.* Then what are the roots? I mean they must be either real or imaginary.

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: You said "the roots are neither real nor purely imaginary" . That means roots with  both a real part and an imaginary part are present.

Comment: A complex number has the form $a+bi$ where $a,b$ are real number variables. Ordinarily, if $b=0$ then we abbreviate $a+0\cdot i = a$ and that's a real number. Also, if $a=0$ then we abbreviate $0+bi=bi$ and that's a purely imaginary number. For example, the roots of $p(x)=x^2+x+1$ are $-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$ and $-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$, neither of which is real, and neither of which is purely imaginary.

Comment: apparently, the source is: JEE ADVANCED 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a vocabulary convention...

While a real number is $r$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$, 
a **purely imaginary number** is a product $r\cdot i$.

If we are using the notation $a+bi$ for arbitrary complex numbers, the purely real numbers have $b=0$ while the purely imaginary numbers have $a=0$.

For $p(x)=x^2+4$, the roots of $p(x)$ are purely imaginary: $\{-2i,+2i\}$. Not all of the roots of the equation $p(p(x))$ are *purely imaginary*.

Comment: +1 I see. The answer provided to me was just worded badly.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate, if $p(x)$ is quadratic, then it must have two roots by The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

So we know $p(x)=A(x-mi)(x-ni)$ for some real numbers A,m,and n.

We know something more, m=-n by the Complex Conjugate Root Theorem, so $p(x)=A(x-mi)(x+mi)$.

What do you get if you multiply that out?

Now plug that result into itself and you get a quartic equation.

Do you know how to find these roots? The quadratic formula might be applicable.